# How to resize a running application in free-form mode?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to programmatically resize the window in which the application is running without losing data in the application (without recreating it)?

P.S: I need to resize a third party app like google chrome, google maps, etc.

My code to run the application in free-form mode

```
val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome")

var options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic()
try {
    val method: Method = ActivityOptions::class.java.getMethod("setLaunchWindowingMode", Int::class.javaPrimitiveType)
    method.invoke(options, 5)
} catch (_: Exception) {}

val windowsSize = Rect(
    0,
    0,
    resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels,
    resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
)
options = options.setLaunchBounds(windowsSize)

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

For the code to work correctly, several options must be enabled in developer mode

```
adb shell settings put global enable_freeform_support  1
adb shell settings put global force_resizable_activities  1
```

Comment: Did you manage to get the resize working?